# adding more then one class to a div with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working again and got this to work. I was just wondering if this is the best way to wright this code?

```
$(window).load(function(){
    var $window = $(window),
    $sticky = $('#contentSideIner'),
    elTop = $sticky.offset().top;

    $window.scroll(function() {
        $sticky.toggleClass('sticky', $window.scrollTop() > elTop);
    });
    $window.scroll(function() {
        $sticky.toggleClass('stickyBottom', $window.scrollTop() > elTop + 4685);
    });
});
```

I had such a hard time to get this function to work in the first place. for the longest time I was told it was not executing at all.

Comment: These kind of questions should be asked in http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: sorry, didn't even know there was a code review page. well repost there

Comment: Why use two separate `.scroll()` event handlers when you could just put two lines of code in one event handler?

Comment: to tell you the truth, I kept on getting errors when I tried that and I think its because I forgot that when I am calling a px value I need only to include the number. I kept putting in "4685px" into the code.

Answer (score 0):

you can combine the toggle classes. $sticky.toggleClass().toggleClass();